# Get selected items from jquery form

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-chosen

I'm using Jquery Chosen (harvesthq.github.io/chosen) to select elements from a list and I want to post the selected items to a form created in Javascript.

I want to create `data` where `data = Array of selected items` but I don't know how to retrieve the selected items with Javascript.

HTML

```
<select name="items[]" data-placeholder="select items" class="chosen-select" multiple tabindex="4">
```

JS

```
var data = XXXX ???

function submitForm(data) {

var jsoned_array = JSON.stringify(data);
var form = document.createElement("form");

form.setAttribute("method", "post");
form.setAttribute("action", "/add_items/");

var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "items");
hiddenField.setAttribute("value", jsoned_array);

form.appendChild(hiddenField);

document.body.appendChild(form);
form.submit();

}
```

Please how do I populate `data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var data = $( "select" ).val();
```

Just regular jQuery.